# Calculate unique ID with time range and repeating identifier

Tags: math, timestamp, numbers, sampling, uniqueidentifier

I collect two datastreams at different sampling rates. They each include a unix timestamp in milliseconds and a product ID. Example:

Data Stream 1 (1ms sampling rate):

| Sample N. | Product ID | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1681921395998 |
| 2 | 124 | 1681921395999 |
| 3 | 124 | 1681921396000 |
| 4 | 124 | 1681921396001 |
| 5 | 124 | 1681921396002 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 47 | 124 | 1681921396044 |
| 48 | 124 | 1681921396045 |
| 49 | 125 | 1681921396046 |

Data Stream 2 (4ms sampling rate):

| Sample N. | Product ID | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1681921395998 |
| 2 | 124 | 1681921396002 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 12 | 124 | 1681921396045 |

I have to group the data of both streams by product. But the product ID isn't unique. It ranges from 1-2500, then repeats. Product ID 124 could be used again after 20 minutes.

And the timestamp also isn't a unique identifier; For Datastream1 the first timestamp for Product 124 was 1681921395999 and for Datastream2 1681921396002. Sometimes they could also match randomly, if the Product ID changes when both streams sample at the same time.

Any ideas how I could use this information to calculate a unique ID that is the same for both datastreams? I tried to play around with rounding, calculating a mean or median, and even combining it with the Product ID, but no success. It still could happen that the IDs aren't the same in some rare cases.

Is this impossible?

Comment: You kind of already answered this yourself? You use the compound key {id, timestamp}. Of course, not know what programming language or data processing framework you're using, that's also about the most someone can say.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The combination of Product ID and timestamp is unique, but not the same for both datastreams. In my example they have different timestamps for the first sample of the product. So the problem is; How can I guarantee that a grouping by Product ID always has the same ID, regardless of Datastream?

Comment: They're completely different data streams, so I have no idea why you'd try to get their row ids to be identical. Store each stream in its own table, then when you need them joined, join them on product id with a conditional about how far apart their timestamps can be to still be considered the same thing? Again, you're not saying what technologies you're using, so no one's going to be able to give you a _real_ answer to the problem you're trying to solve (which isn't "what can I use as unique id" but is "how can I collate this data")